# Does 'Then' after 'And' require a comma?

Tags: coordinating-conjunctions

I was writing a compound sentence, that required a 'Then' after the coordinating conjunction.
I was wondering if the 'Then' needed a comma before and after it, such as thus:

"It is best to review once or twice, and, then, move on."

If it should be included or omitted, I'd appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the parenthetical commas you propose actually change the meaning of *then.* This is because they change the stress afforded the word and, to a lesser extent, its pronunciation.

Without them, "review it and then move on", *then* means "after that" [[Oxford sense 2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/then)]. In this case, *then* receives the stress rather than *and*.

With the commas, "review it and, then, move on", *then* means "in that case; therefore" [[Oxford sense 3](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/then)]. In this sentence, because *then* is effectively in parentheses, *and* receives the stress and *then* is relegated to secondary importance. It is this which changes the meaning.

In passing, if the *then* is **required,** it cannot be parenthetical, cannot be contained in commas, and cannot have the meaning of "therefore". However, it's not actually required even when it means "after that", because the two actions have to be carried out in sequence: "review it and move on". Thus it is when it **does** have the meaning of "therefore" that it **is** required, and in that case it needs the commas to give it that meaning. It's rather paradoxical that a required word must apparently be parenthetical to give it its required meaning.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great answer about the relevance of stresses!